# SSPI WDigest Server Vaildation Failure

Tags: winapi, sspi

I'm trying to get the Win32 SSPI API to validate a [challenge response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/sspi-with-microsoft-digest-ssp-tasks) from a client.  The call to [AcceptSecurityContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sspi/nf-sspi-acceptsecuritycontext) is always failing with either SEC_E_INVALID_TOKEN (0x80090308) or SEC_E_INTERNAL_ERROR (0x80090304).

I've stripped down the problem to this sample code:

```
#define SECURITY_WIN32
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>
#include <security.h>
#include <wdigest.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment(lib, "Secur32.lib")

using namespace std::string_literals;

int main()
{
    auto const realm = L"realm"s;
    auto const client_method = "GET"s;
    auto const client_target = L"HTTP/TARGETMACHINE"s;
    auto const client_uri = L"/"s;
    auto const client_uri_utf8 = "/"s;

    // server generate digest challenge
    PSecPkgInfoW package_info;
    auto result = QuerySecurityPackageInfoW(const_cast<LPWSTR>(WDIGEST_SP_NAME_W), &package_info);
    if (result != SEC_E_OK) 
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    CredHandle serverCredHandle;
    TimeStamp lifetime;
    result = AcquireCredentialsHandleW(nullptr, const_cast<LPWSTR>(WDIGEST_SP_NAME_W), SECPKG_CRED_INBOUND, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, &serverCredHandle, &lifetime);
    if (result != SEC_E_OK)
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    SecBuffer challengeInBuffers[5];

    // token
    challengeInBuffers[0].BufferType = SECBUFFER_TOKEN;
    challengeInBuffers[0].cbBuffer = 0;
    challengeInBuffers[0].pvBuffer = nullptr;

    // method
    challengeInBuffers[1].BufferType = SECBUFFER_PKG_PARAMS;
    challengeInBuffers[1].cbBuffer = 0;
    challengeInBuffers[1].pvBuffer = nullptr;

    // uri
    challengeInBuffers[2].BufferType = SECBUFFER_PKG_PARAMS;
    challengeInBuffers[2].cbBuffer = 0;
    challengeInBuffers[2].pvBuffer = nullptr;

    // body hash
    challengeInBuffers[3].BufferType = SECBUFFER_PKG_PARAMS;
    challengeInBuffers[3].cbBuffer = 0;
    challengeInBuffers[3].pvBuffer = nullptr;

    // realm
    challengeInBuffers[4].BufferType = SECBUFFER_PKG_PARAMS;
    challengeInBuffers[4].cbBuffer = realm.size() * sizeof(wchar_t);
    challengeInBuffers[4].pvBuffer = const_cast<void*>(static_cast<void const*>(realm.c_str()));

    SecBufferDesc challengeInBufferDesc;

    challengeInBufferDesc.ulVersion = 0;
    challengeInBufferDesc.cBuffers = 5;
    challengeInBufferDesc.pBuffers  = challengeInBuffers;

    std::string challenge;
    challenge.resize(package_info->cbMaxToken);

    SecBuffer challengeOutBuffer;
    challengeOutBuffer.BufferType = SECBUFFER_TOKEN;
    challengeOutBuffer.cbBuffer = challenge.size();
    challengeOutBuffer.pvBuffer = const_cast<void*>(static_cast<void const*>(challenge.data()));

    SecBufferDesc challengeOutBufferDesc;
    challengeOutBufferDesc.ulVersion = 0;
    challengeOutBufferDesc.cBuffers = 1;
    challengeOutBufferDesc.pBuffers = &challengeOutBuffer;

    CtxtHandle serverContextHandle;
    unsigned long outContextAttributes;
    result = AcceptSecurityContext(&serverCredHandle, nullptr, &challengeInBufferDesc, 0, SECURITY_NETWORK_DREP, &serverContextHandle, &challengeOutBufferDesc, &outContextAttributes, &lifetime);
    if (result != SEC_I_CONTINUE_NEEDED)
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    challenge.resize(challengeOutBuffer.cbBuffer);

    std::cout << "Challenge: [" << challenge << "]\n";


    // client challenge response generation
    SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY_W auth_data;
    auth_data.Flags = SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY_UNICODE;
    auth_data.User = nullptr;
    auth_data.UserLength = 0;
    auth_data.Domain = nullptr;
    auth_data.DomainLength = 0;
    auth_data.Password = nullptr;
    auth_data.PasswordLength = 0;

    CredHandle clientCredHandle;
    result = AcquireCredentialsHandleW(nullptr, const_cast<LPWSTR>(WDIGEST_SP_NAME_W), SECPKG_CRED_OUTBOUND, nullptr, &auth_data, nullptr, nullptr, &clientCredHandle, &lifetime);
    if (result != SEC_E_OK)
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    SecBuffer challengeResponseInBuffers[4];

    // token
    challengeResponseInBuffers[0].BufferType = SECBUFFER_TOKEN;
    challengeResponseInBuffers[0].cbBuffer = challenge.size();
    challengeResponseInBuffers[0].pvBuffer = const_cast<void*>(static_cast<void const*>(challenge.data()));

    // method
    challengeResponseInBuffers[1].BufferType = SECBUFFER_PKG_PARAMS;
    challengeResponseInBuffers[1].cbBuffer = client_method.size();
    challengeResponseInBuffers[1].pvBuffer = const_cast<void*>(static_cast<void const*>(client_method.data()));

    // body hash
    challengeResponseInBuffers[2].BufferType = SECBUFFER_PKG_PARAMS;
    challengeResponseInBuffers[2].cbBuffer = 0;
    challengeResponseInBuffers[2].pvBuffer = nullptr;

    // target
    challengeResponseInBuffers[3].BufferType = SECBUFFER_STREAM;
    challengeResponseInBuffers[3].cbBuffer = client_target.size() * sizeof(wchar_t);
    challengeResponseInBuffers[3].pvBuffer = const_cast<void*>(static_cast<void const*>(client_target.data()));

    SecBufferDesc challengeResponseInBufferDesc;

    challengeResponseInBufferDesc.ulVersion = 0;
    challengeResponseInBufferDesc.cBuffers = 4;
    challengeResponseInBufferDesc.pBuffers  = challengeResponseInBuffers;

    std::string challengeResponse;
    challengeResponse.resize(package_info->cbMaxToken);

    SecBuffer challengeResponseOutBuffer;
    challengeResponseOutBuffer.BufferType = SECBUFFER_TOKEN;
    challengeResponseOutBuffer.cbBuffer = challengeResponse.size();
    challengeResponseOutBuffer.pvBuffer = const_cast<void*>(static_cast<void const*>(challengeResponse.data()));

    SecBufferDesc challengeResponseOutBufferDesc;
    challengeResponseOutBufferDesc.ulVersion = 0;
    challengeResponseOutBufferDesc.cBuffers = 1;
    challengeResponseOutBufferDesc.pBuffers = &challengeResponseOutBuffer;

    CtxtHandle clientContextHandle;
    result = InitializeSecurityContextW(&clientCredHandle, nullptr, const_cast<SEC_WCHAR*>(client_uri.c_str()), 0, 0, SECURITY_NETWORK_DREP, &challengeResponseInBufferDesc, 0, &clientContextHandle, &challengeResponseOutBufferDesc, &outContextAttributes, &lifetime);
    if(result != SEC_E_OK)
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    challengeResponse.resize(challengeResponseOutBuffer.cbBuffer);

    std::cout << "Challenge Response: [" << challengeResponse << "]\n";


    // server verify challenge response

    SecBuffer verifyChallengeResponseInBuffers[5];

    // token
    verifyChallengeResponseInBuffers[0].BufferType = SECBUFFER_TOKEN;
    verifyChallengeResponseInBuffers[0].cbBuffer = challengeResponse.size();
    verifyChallengeResponseInBuffers[0].pvBuffer = const_cast<void*>(static_cast<void const*>(challengeResponse.data()));

    // method
    verifyChallengeResponseInBuffers[1].BufferType = SECBUFFER_PKG_PARAMS;
    verifyChallengeResponseInBuffers[1].cbBuffer = client_method.size();
    verifyChallengeResponseInBuffers[1].pvBuffer = const_cast<void*>(static_cast<void const*>(client_method.data()));

    // uri
    verifyChallengeResponseInBuffers[2].BufferType = SECBUFFER_PKG_PARAMS;
    verifyChallengeResponseInBuffers[2].cbBuffer = client_uri_utf8.size();
    verifyChallengeResponseInBuffers[2].pvBuffer = const_cast<void*>(static_cast<void const*>(client_uri_utf8.data()));

    // body hash
    verifyChallengeResponseInBuffers[3].BufferType = SECBUFFER_PKG_PARAMS;
    verifyChallengeResponseInBuffers[3].cbBuffer = 0;
    verifyChallengeResponseInBuffers[3].pvBuffer = nullptr;

    // realm
    verifyChallengeResponseInBuffers[4].BufferType = SECBUFFER_PKG_PARAMS;
    verifyChallengeResponseInBuffers[4].cbBuffer = realm.size() * sizeof(wchar_t);
    verifyChallengeResponseInBuffers[4].pvBuffer = const_cast<void*>(static_cast<void const*>(realm.c_str()));

    SecBufferDesc verifyChallengeResponseInBufferDesc;

    verifyChallengeResponseInBufferDesc.ulVersion = 0;
    verifyChallengeResponseInBufferDesc.cBuffers = 5;
    verifyChallengeResponseInBufferDesc.pBuffers  = verifyChallengeResponseInBuffers;

    std::string verifyChallengeResponse;
    verifyChallengeResponse.resize(package_info->cbMaxToken);

    SecBuffer verifyChallengeResponseOutBuffer;
    challengeOutBuffer.BufferType = SECBUFFER_TOKEN;
    challengeOutBuffer.cbBuffer = verifyChallengeResponse.size();
    challengeOutBuffer.pvBuffer = const_cast<void*>(static_cast<void const*>(verifyChallengeResponse.data()));

    SecBufferDesc verifyChallengeResponseOutBufferDesc;
    verifyChallengeResponseOutBufferDesc.ulVersion = 0;
    verifyChallengeResponseOutBufferDesc.cBuffers = 1;
    verifyChallengeResponseOutBufferDesc.pBuffers = &verifyChallengeResponseOutBuffer;

    result = AcceptSecurityContext(&serverCredHandle, &serverContextHandle, &verifyChallengeResponseInBufferDesc, 0, SECURITY_NETWORK_DREP, &serverContextHandle, &verifyChallengeResponseOutBufferDesc, &outContextAttributes, &lifetime);
    if (result != SEC_I_COMPLETE_NEEDED)
    {
        std::cout << "Challenge Response Verification Failed with [0x" << std::hex << result << "]";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::cout << "Challenge Response Verified";
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The output I get is:

> Challenge:
>   [qop="auth",algorithm=MD5-sess,nonce="+Upgraded+v1db70e06e6d35dfd59df6fcd8d3cf7f7671d23e810144d5012972e89ccadaa398f05e8d5ab7a9c0eb3d52b00f4446530312ac45e30f4ac02c",charset=utf-8,realm="realm"]
>
> Challenge Response:
>   [username="",realm="realm",nonce="+Upgraded+v1db70e06e6d35dfd59df6fcd8d3cf7f7671d23e810144d5012972e89ccadaa398f05e8d5ab7a9c0eb3d52b00f4446530312ac45e30f4ac02c",uri="/",cnonce="+Upgraded+v15c1d89757bd55776df6e2788dcdca9220f6aa1af03856d237a0e37a8136b5a44",nc=00000001,algorithm=MD5-sess,response="ee315ddeed6f2d3d68b6cafff9f7d52e",qop="auth",charset=utf-8,hashed-dirs="service-name,channel-binding",service-name="",channel-binding="00000000000000000000000000000000"]
>
> Challenge Response Verification Failed with [0x80090308]

I've tried varying the inputs to the challenge / challenge response and verification parts with no real results.

The MSDN documentation doesn't seem to be a lot of help and most of my insights to this digest API have come from the .net reference source here:
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/_NTAuthentication.cs

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

UPDATE:

Output from my machine with UseLogonCredential set to "1" (although I tested with it test to "1" and "0" with the exact same output) for the sample application in the answer below I get the following output:

```
Capabilities:   0x800304
wVersion:       0x1
Max Token Size: 0x1000
SERVER: AcquireCredentialsHandle SUCCESS
CLIENT: AcquireCredentialsHandle SUCCESS
CLIENT: InitializeSecurityContext: SEC_I__CONTINUE_NEEDED
SERVER: AcceptSecurityContext: SEC_I__CONTINUE_NEEDED
CLIENT: InitializeSecurityContext: SEC_I_CONTINUE_NEEDED
AcceptSecurityContext SUCCESS
InitializeSecurityContext (2) failed with 0x8009030A
```

This to me looks like it's working but I don't see why you need the last client side InitializeSecurityContext anyway as the server side has verified it?

Also I can take out the first "CLIENT: InitializeSecurityContext" as it's not needed and returns a "blank" token anyway and it still works fine if removed.

What I can't get going is using the current users credentials for the client, I have to supply a SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY with valid credentials.  Is there any reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wdigest package is disabled by default since it uses MD5 which is not secure. 
You must enable the package in the registry to use the code. [KB2871997 and Wdigest – Part 1](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/kfalde/2014/11/01/kb2871997-and-wdigest-part-1/). And why do you want to use wdigest since it isn’t secure anymore.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define SECURITY_WIN32
#include <sspi.h>

void wmain(int argc, WCHAR *argv[])
{
    SECURITY_STATUS ss;
    SecPkgInfo      *spi = {0};

    ss = QuerySecurityPackageInfo(L"wdigest", &spi);
    if (ss != SEC_E_OK)
    {
        wprintf(L"QuerySecurityPackageInfo failed with %u\n", ss);
        return;
    }

    wprintf(L"Capabilities:   0x%X\n", spi->fCapabilities);
    wprintf(L"wVersion:       0x%X\n", spi->wVersion);
    wprintf(L"Max Token Size: 0x%X\n", spi->cbMaxToken);

    LPBYTE lpbOut = NULL;
    lpbOut = (LPBYTE)LocalAlloc(LPTR, spi->cbMaxToken);
    if (lpbOut == NULL)
    {
        wprintf(L"LocalAlloc failed with %u\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    CredHandle ServerCred;
    CredHandle ClientCred;
    TimeStamp LifeTime;

    // server side
    ss = AcquireCredentialsHandle(NULL, L"wdigest", SECPKG_CRED_INBOUND, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, &ServerCred, &LifeTime);
    if (ss != SEC_E_OK)
    {
        wprintf(L"AcquireCredentialsHandle failed with %u\n", ss);
        return;
    }
    else
        wprintf(L"SERVER: AcquireCredentialsHandle SUCCESS\n");

    // client side
    SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY   AuthIdentity;


    WCHAR szDomain[] = L"domain";
    WCHAR szPassword[] = L"password";
    WCHAR szUser[] = L"user";



    AuthIdentity.Domain = (unsigned short *)szDomain;
    AuthIdentity.DomainLength = (unsigned long)wcslen(szDomain);
    AuthIdentity.Password = (unsigned short *)szPassword;
    AuthIdentity.PasswordLength = (unsigned long)wcslen(szPassword);
    AuthIdentity.User = (unsigned short *)szUser;
    AuthIdentity.UserLength = (unsigned long)wcslen(szUser);
    AuthIdentity.Flags = SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY_UNICODE;

    /*
    AuthIdentity.Domain = (unsigned short *)NULL;
    AuthIdentity.DomainLength = (unsigned long)0;
    AuthIdentity.Password = (unsigned short *)NULL;
    AuthIdentity.PasswordLength = (unsigned long)0;
    AuthIdentity.User = (unsigned short *)NULL;
    AuthIdentity.UserLength = (unsigned long)0;
    AuthIdentity.Flags = SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY_UNICODE;*/


    ss = AcquireCredentialsHandle(NULL, L"wdigest", SECPKG_CRED_OUTBOUND, NULL, &AuthIdentity, NULL, NULL, &ClientCred, &LifeTime);
    if (ss != SEC_E_OK)
    {
        wprintf(L"OUTBOUND: AcquireCredentialsHandle failed with 0x%X\n", ss);
        return;
    }
    else
        wprintf(L"CLIENT: AcquireCredentialsHandle SUCCESS\n");

    SecBufferDesc OutputBuffers;
    SecBuffer     TempTokensOut[6];

    OutputBuffers.ulVersion = SECBUFFER_VERSION;
    OutputBuffers.cBuffers  = 1;
    OutputBuffers.pBuffers  = TempTokensOut;

    TempTokensOut[0].BufferType = SECBUFFER_TOKEN;
    TempTokensOut[0].cbBuffer   = spi->cbMaxToken;
    TempTokensOut[0].pvBuffer   = lpbOut;

    CtxtHandle ClientCtxtHandle;
    ULONG ClientContextRetFlags = 0;
    BOOL  bContinue             = FALSE;

    ss = InitializeSecurityContext(&ClientCred, NULL, L"HTTP//test.com", /*ISC_REQ_INTEGRITY | ISC_REQ_CONFIDENTIALITY | */ISC_REQ_REPLAY_DETECT | ISC_REQ_CONNECTION, NULL, SECURITY_NATIVE_DREP, NULL, NULL,
                                   &ClientCtxtHandle, &OutputBuffers, &ClientContextRetFlags, &LifeTime);
    if (ss == SEC_I_CONTINUE_NEEDED)
    {
        bContinue = TRUE;

        wprintf(L"CLIENT: InitializeSecurityContext: SEC_I__CONTINUE_NEEDED\n");
    }
    else
    {
        if (ss != SEC_E_OK)
        {
            wprintf(L"InitializeSecurityContext failed with 0x%X\n", ss);
            return;
        }
    }

    SecBufferDesc InputBuffers;
    SecBuffer     TempTokensIn[10];

    LPBYTE lpbIn = NULL;
    lpbIn = (LPBYTE)LocalAlloc(LPTR, spi->cbMaxToken);
    if (lpbIn == NULL)
    {
        wprintf(L"LocalAlloc failed with %u\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    InputBuffers.ulVersion = SECBUFFER_VERSION;
    InputBuffers.cBuffers  = 1;
    InputBuffers.pBuffers  = TempTokensIn;

    TempTokensIn[0].BufferType = SECBUFFER_TOKEN;
    TempTokensIn[0].cbBuffer   = TempTokensOut[0].cbBuffer;
    TempTokensIn[0].pvBuffer   = TempTokensOut[0].pvBuffer;

    OutputBuffers.ulVersion = SECBUFFER_VERSION;
    OutputBuffers.cBuffers  = 1;
    OutputBuffers.pBuffers  = TempTokensOut;

    TempTokensOut[0].BufferType = SECBUFFER_TOKEN;
    TempTokensOut[0].cbBuffer = spi->cbMaxToken;
    TempTokensOut[0].pvBuffer = lpbOut;

    ULONG      TargetDataRep = 0;
    CtxtHandle ServerCtxtHandle;
    ULONG      ServerContextRetFlags = 0;

    ss = AcceptSecurityContext(&ServerCred, NULL, &InputBuffers, 0 /*ASC_REQ_INTEGRITY | ASC_REQ_CONFIDENTIALITY*/, TargetDataRep, &ServerCtxtHandle, &OutputBuffers, &ServerContextRetFlags, &LifeTime);
    if (ss == SEC_I_CONTINUE_NEEDED)
    {
        bContinue = TRUE;

        wprintf(L"SERVER: AcceptSecurityContext: SEC_I__CONTINUE_NEEDED\n");
    }
    else
    {
        if (ss != SEC_E_OK)
        {
            wprintf(L"AcceptSecurityContext failed with 0x%X\n", ss);
            return;
        }
    }

    InputBuffers.ulVersion = SECBUFFER_VERSION;
    InputBuffers.cBuffers  = 1;
    InputBuffers.pBuffers  = TempTokensIn;

    TempTokensIn[0].BufferType = SECBUFFER_TOKEN;
    TempTokensIn[0].cbBuffer   = TempTokensOut[0].cbBuffer;
    TempTokensIn[0].pvBuffer   = TempTokensOut[0].pvBuffer;

    OutputBuffers.ulVersion = SECBUFFER_VERSION;
    OutputBuffers.cBuffers  = 1;
    OutputBuffers.pBuffers  = TempTokensOut;

    TempTokensOut[0].BufferType = SECBUFFER_TOKEN;
    TempTokensOut[0].cbBuffer = spi->cbMaxToken;
    TempTokensOut[0].pvBuffer = lpbOut;

    ss = InitializeSecurityContext(&ClientCred, NULL, L"HTTP//test.com", /*ISC_REQ_INTEGRITY | ISC_REQ_CONFIDENTIALITY | */ISC_REQ_REPLAY_DETECT | ISC_REQ_CONNECTION, NULL, SECURITY_NATIVE_DREP, &InputBuffers, NULL,
                                   &ClientCtxtHandle, &OutputBuffers, &ClientContextRetFlags, &LifeTime);
    if (ss == SEC_I_CONTINUE_NEEDED)
    {
        bContinue = TRUE;

        wprintf(L"CLIENT: InitializeSecurityContext: SEC_I_CONTINUE_NEEDED\n");
    }
    else
    {
        if (ss != SEC_E_OK)
        {
            wprintf(L"InitializeSecurityContext (2) failed with 0x%X\n", ss);
            return;
        }
    }

    InputBuffers.ulVersion = SECBUFFER_VERSION;
    InputBuffers.cBuffers  = 1;
    InputBuffers.pBuffers  = TempTokensIn;

    TempTokensIn[0].BufferType = SECBUFFER_TOKEN;
    TempTokensIn[0].cbBuffer   = TempTokensOut[0].cbBuffer;
    TempTokensIn[0].pvBuffer   = TempTokensOut[0].pvBuffer;

    OutputBuffers.ulVersion = SECBUFFER_VERSION;
    OutputBuffers.cBuffers  = 1;
    OutputBuffers.pBuffers  = TempTokensOut;

    TempTokensOut[0].BufferType = SECBUFFER_TOKEN;
    TempTokensOut[0].cbBuffer = spi->cbMaxToken;
    TempTokensOut[0].pvBuffer = lpbOut;

    ss = AcceptSecurityContext(&ServerCred, NULL, &InputBuffers, 0 /*ASC_REQ_INTEGRITY | ASC_REQ_CONFIDENTIALITY*/, TargetDataRep, &ServerCtxtHandle, &OutputBuffers, &ServerContextRetFlags, &LifeTime);
    if (ss == SEC_I_CONTINUE_NEEDED)
    {
        bContinue = TRUE;
    }
    else if (ss != SEC_E_OK)
    {
        wprintf(L"AcceptSecurityContext (2) failed with 0x%X\n", ss);
        return;
    }
    else
        wprintf(L"AcceptSecurityContext SUCCESS\n");

    InputBuffers.ulVersion = SECBUFFER_VERSION;
    InputBuffers.cBuffers  = 1;
    InputBuffers.pBuffers  = TempTokensIn;

    TempTokensIn[0].BufferType = SECBUFFER_TOKEN;
    TempTokensIn[0].cbBuffer   = TempTokensOut[0].cbBuffer;
    TempTokensIn[0].pvBuffer   = TempTokensOut[0].pvBuffer;

    OutputBuffers.ulVersion = SECBUFFER_VERSION;
    OutputBuffers.cBuffers  = 1;
    OutputBuffers.pBuffers  = TempTokensOut;

    TempTokensOut[0].BufferType = SECBUFFER_TOKEN;
    TempTokensOut[0].cbBuffer = spi->cbMaxToken;
    TempTokensOut[0].pvBuffer = lpbOut;

    ss = InitializeSecurityContext(&ClientCred, NULL, L"HTTP//test.com", /*ISC_REQ_INTEGRITY | ISC_REQ_CONFIDENTIALITY |*/ ISC_REQ_REPLAY_DETECT | ISC_REQ_CONNECTION, NULL, SECURITY_NATIVE_DREP, &InputBuffers, NULL,
                                   &ClientCtxtHandle, &OutputBuffers, &ClientContextRetFlags, &LifeTime);
    if (ss == SEC_I_CONTINUE_NEEDED)
    {
        bContinue = TRUE;
    }
    else if (ss != SEC_E_OK)
    {
        wprintf(L"InitializeSecurityContext (2) failed with 0x%X\n", ss);
        return;
    }
    else
        wprintf(L"InitializeSecurityContext SUCCESS\n");

    ss = FreeCredentialsHandle(&ClientCred);
    if (ss != SEC_E_OK)
    {
        wprintf(L"FreeCredentialsHandle failed with %u\n", ss);
        return;
    }

    ss = FreeCredentialsHandle(&ServerCred);
    if (ss != SEC_E_OK)
    {
        wprintf(L"FreeCredentialsHandle failed with %u\n", ss);
        return;
    }

    if (lpbOut != NULL)
        LocalFree((HLOCAL)lpbOut);

    if (lpbIn != NULL)
        LocalFree((HLOCAL)lpbIn);

    if (spi != NULL)
        FreeContextBuffer((PVOID)spi);
}
```

Can this sample work when the wdigest package is enabled ?

Comment: The article doesn't say wdigest is disabled, it's saying "caching of credentials in memory" is disabled.  wdigest is used by http servers for basic auth.  MD5 is considered "severely compromised" but not completely unsecure.  AFAIK MD5 usage in http basic auth is considered ok still when layered over SSL (HTTPS).  Why I want to use wdigest is to implement HTTP basic auth for windows credentials just like ISS can...

Comment: "caching of credentials in memory" is disabled, which leads to malfunction. Have Challenge Response Verification succeeded using this method ?

Comment: Setting "UseLogonCredential" to "1" (& rebooting) still gives me the same result, in that it doesn't work in the same way.  There is something I'm not understanding on how to use the verify but there is no documentation on how to verify.

Comment: Also, statements like "The observed change in behavior when the UseLogonCredential value is set to 0 is that you may notice that credentials are required more frequently when you use WDigest."  indicates that WDigest is not disabled with the setting of UseLogonCredential.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/2871997/microsoft-security-advisory-update-to-improve-credentials-protection-a

Comment: I add the sample code in the answer, please check it.

Comment: Have checked the sample code and updated my answer with my results.

Comment: @ShanePowell Are you able to use the Digest authentication now? And would you mind sharing the specific reason for using this authentication since it uses MD5 as the hashing algorithm and that is an old and unsecure algorithm.

Comment: Yes I did get it working but we haven't decided if we should use it or not.  There are two specific scenarios where we don't really have control over the clients but wish to move away from our own client authentication and use windows domain authentication.  Where we have control over the client we are using SSPI.  Where we don't is where we are the SIP server and/or web server where the clients are hardware devices (like IP phones) where we have no control over the client software and they use standard digest access authentication.